# Haystack Not Returning Results that Solr Admin Console Highlights

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I've recently set up solr and haystack to search one of my django models.  I attempted to modify the default solr schema built by haystack to use the `NGramTokenizerFactory`:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="32" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="32" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have a bunch of one or two word entries in my database which I would like to match against the user's query.  So for example, I might have one object with title "dog" and another with title "cat".  If the user searches for "dog cat" then I would like to return both the dog and cat objects for that query.

Similarly, if I search for "my cool website" I would like the field with "website" to be returned.

I tried using the solr admin interface to check to make sure my queries were getting matched.  Everything seems okay there:
[image]:
The issue is when I use the haystack default search interface to search for that same query:
[image]

As you can see, no results are found.  I tried using KeywordFactory and a bunch of different solr configurations.  If I'm not mistaken then the query *should* be getting matched.  I'm not sure why haystack is coming up empty though.

Thanks for any help / suggestions on if this is the best way to go about such a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few month ago I worked with `django-haystack` and solr. I also had a problems with making some special queries to solr.
Actually it should be solved by addng next line to `settings.py`:

```
HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR' # actually has no effect...
```

But it does not work for me.

So, in my case it was solved by subclassing `SearchView` class. This is small snippet from my project:

```
# views.py:
from haystack.views import SearchView

class PeriodicalSearchView(SearchView):
  def get_results(self):
    """
    Fetches the results via the form.
    Returns an empty list if there's no query to search with.
    """
    if not (self.form.is_valid() and self.form.cleaned_data['q']):
        return self.form.no_query_found()

    query = self.form.cleaned_data['q']

    words = iter(set(query.split()))
    word = words.next()
    sqs = self.form.searchqueryset.filter(text=word) # actually I have one more field here...
    for word in words:
        sqs = sqs.filter_or(title=word).filter_or(text=word)

    if self.load_all:
        sqs = sqs.load_all()

    return sqs

  def __call__(self, request, template_name=None):
    """
    Generates the actual response to the search.
    Relies on internal, overridable methods to construct the response.
    """
    if template_name:
        self.template = template_name

    return super(PeriodicalSearchView, self).__call__(request)
```

And urls.py

```
# urls.py:
from .views import PeriodicalSearchView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^search/$', PeriodicalSearchView(template='template_search.html'), 
    name='haystack_search'),
)
```

And that's it.

Comment: thanks for the complete answer.  this achieved what i wanted.