# Django Search: Setting Haystack_Default_Operator = 'OR' has no effect

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm using Haystack and Whoosh to do search with a django site I'm building. I'd like to use an OR operator on search terms (e.g. "Search String" will find objects with text "Search" OR "String" instead of "Search" AND "String")

This seems pretty straight forward as haystack allows you to override the default "AND" operator by setting [HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR'](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.2.0/settings.html) in your settings.py file.

Unfortunately, adding this to my settings.py has had no effect. I've found a couple of tangential references to this behavior on stackoverflow, but no solution. I've also found an [issue posted on github](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/904), but it's been there since last year with no comments or classification.

I may be doing something wrong, so figured I'd post here and see if there's a solution. I'm kinda stuck without one!

My haystack settings in my settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
    },
}
HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR'
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

My view:

```
from haystack import views as hsviews

def search_test(request):
    return hsviews.basic_search(request)
```

My search_indexes.py file:

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from myApp.models import MyModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.NgramField(document=True, use_template= True)
    isPublic = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='isPubliclyVisible')
    brand = indexes.CharField(model_attr='brand')
    model = indexes.CharField(model_attr='model')
    owner = indexes.CharField(model_attr='owner')
    owner_username = indexes.CharField()
    obj_type = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return MyModel

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(isPubliclyVisible = True)

    def prepare_owner_username(self, obj):
        return obj.owner.user.username

    def prepare_obj_type(self,obj):
        return 'MyModel'
```

I did find this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675252/haystack-not-returning-results-that-solr-admin-console-highlights/5680388#5680388) (which I haven't tested/thought through for my solution yet), but I figured this warranted its own question in case I/we are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Haystack built-in *basic_search* function, I would suggest writing your own view so you would have more control of how the search queries are performed. That way, you can process more complex searches by extending your view or custom search query function, plus it would be easier to test.

For example, you can build separate SearchQuerySet filters to perform each of the keywords you're seaching for, then "OR" them together, like this:

```
def get_query(request):
    """
    This function retrieves any query terms (e.g q=search+term)
    from the request object.

    :param request: request object
    :returns: query terms as a list (split on whitespace)
    """
    query = None
    qs_keyword = 'q'
    if (qs_keyword in request.GET) and request.GET[qs_keyword].strip():
        query_string = request.GET[qs_keyword]
        query = query_string.split()
    return query

def perform_query(request):
    """
    This is a helper function to perform the actual query.

    You can extend this to handle more complicated searches using AND,
    OR, boolean qualifiers, etc.

    :param request: request object
    :returns: SearchQuerySet results
    """
    query = get_query(request)
    if not query:
        results = EmptySearchQuerySet()
    else:
        results = SearchQuerySet()
        for search_term in query:
            # you can use the "|" (or) operator
            results |= results.filter(content=search_term)
            # or else use "filter_or"
            # results = results.filter_or(content=search_term)
    return results

def your_search_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    This is your search view to process the query and display your results.
    """
    # call "perform_query" to do the actual search
    results = perform_query(request)

    # do the rest of your view processing ...
    return render_to_response(etc.)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have time to give this a try this weekend, but will update in the next couple days.

Comment: Update: This looks like it should do the trick nicely -- unfortunately I'm getting some more bad behavior from Haystack. SearchQuerySet().all() returns an empty list. But if I use the basic_search() view, it works fine, so I know the index is working.

Comment: You might want to try doing a query manually in the django shell to test out the steps to build the SearchQuerySet results according to your requirements. That is a good way to test your code in isolation from all the hidden processing of a view.

Comment: yea, this is actually where I was getting the empty list. In shell I did: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet, results = SearchQuerySet().all(), results.count()

Comment: Update: still not sure why I'm getting those results in command line, but got the code working -- so good enough! I realised I was using a POST to hit the search -- which mis-matched the code above. Thanks for the help! If you happen to know why I might get an empty string in the command line, let me know.

Comment: When you do an an initial SearchQuerySet() Haystack will return a lazy object that's empty -- since you're not matching anything in the "all" (which is a no-op method). If you know you have data that will match "search" and "term," I would try: results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content="search").filter_or(content="term") amd see if that returns the results you expect.

Comment: Ah perfect. replacing the .all() with a filter fixed the empty results in command line. Thanks!